# HTML page can't load CSS file, resource not found error

Tags: html, css

I am baffled as to why this isn't working.  Below is the reference to the css file in the head tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="Candidate.css"/>
</head>
<body>
```

Here is a screen shot of the directory path and console output:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Candidate.css is in correct directory? based on error ur Candidate.css is locate at root folder?

Comment: I have tried changing the path to relative path and absolute paths and received the same error.   It is strange.

Comment: Can you navigate the the CSS file directly from browser? Probably not related but the `<script>` tag should be either in the `<head>` or `<body>` tags. Where is the CSS file? Same directory as `index`?  Or is it in a `styles`, `css` or similar folder?

Comment: Should have mentioned that the file: index is the file I have above showing the HTML script.  The Candidate.css file is in the same directory as index.

I wil try navigating directly to it.

Comment: The server you are using might need to be configured to allow the serving of css files. Try and enter a url to the css file directly into the browsers navbar.

Comment: Is your html file really called "(index)" without an extension? Also, off topic, but there is an error in your HTML: the script should go i the head.

Comment: No it is index.html, it just shows that way in chromes dev tools.

Answer (score 1):

Try getting the entire path to your file.

So if your using xampp your path might be:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\website\css_folder_name\Candidate.css
```

However in practice your relative path is usually used so if your css file is in its own folder and your `index.html` is in the root directory where the folder for your css is you would type:

```
..\Candidate.css
```

The `..\` is a way of referencing the folder one level higher

Comment: I prefer using relative references when linking my styles because it becomes easier to move code around. That way if folder names change you do not need to go edit the path to contain the correct folder names

Comment: I would this problem with many of my website when I started learning HTML now I just use relative references always. It's also really convenient when you need to move your website from one domain to another because you do not need to change multiple lines of code.